# How do I get a python program to rerun itself

Tags: python

I want the code below to automatically rerun itself any ideas hwo to do this? Btw I am new to stack overflow and python itself so If I am doing anything wrong on either please let me know, Thanks

```
import sys
import os
import random 
answer_correct_message = random.choice(['Well done', 'Correct answer','Nice one','Thats correct!'])
answer_wrong_message = random.choice(['Unlucky','Thats wrong','Nope'])
random_num_1 = random.randint(1,10)
random_num_2 = random.randint(1,10)


def question_asker_and_answerer():
    q2 = input("What is " + str(random_num_1) + " + " + str(random_num_2) + "?")
    if q2 == random_num_1 + random_num_2:
        the_questions = True
        if the_questions == True:
            return (answer_correct_message)
        else:
            return (answer_wrong_message)
    else:
        the_questions = False
        if the_questions == True:
            return (answer_correct_message)
        else:
            print(answer_wrong_message)


print question_asker_and_answerer()
```

Comment: Have you considered a loop?

Answer (score 2):

This is not a situation where you are need a program to rerun itself. That sort of requirement is when you want a script to run as a daemon. This is simply a matter of creating a loop

```
while True:
   print question_asker_and_answerer()
```

Comment: See my answer: you also need to modify the function if you want the program to be useful!

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems here:

- how to iterate;
- how to make sure that the various randomly-chosen variables are different each pass through.

Just looping over the existing function, or getting it to recurse (as in a couple of other answers) solves the first of these problems (actually, recursing really doesn't, since Python doesn't have tail-call elimination, so it will run out of stack eventually).

To solve both of them you need to make the randomly-chosen variables local to the function, and then loop.  I have also modified it so it returns the string to print rather than printing it, in the case of a wrong answer (last line of function).

```
import sys
import os
import random 

def question_asker_and_answerer():
    answer_correct_message = random.choice(['Well done', 'Correct answer',
                                            'Nice one','Thats correct!'])
    answer_wrong_message = random.choice(['Unlucky','Thats wrong','Nope'])
    random_num_1 = random.randint(1,10)
    random_num_2 = random.randint(1,10)
    q2 = input("What is " + str(random_num_1) + " + " + str(random_num_2) + "?")
    if q2 == random_num_1 + random_num_2:
        the_questions = True
        if the_questions == True:
            return (answer_correct_message)
        else:
            return (answer_wrong_message)
    else:
        the_questions = False
        if the_questions == True:
            return (answer_correct_message)
        else:
            return (answer_wrong_message)


while True:
    print question_asker_and_answerer()
```

Comment: this is a pretty good answer. Not quite sure why it got a down vote. +1 from me

Comment: Thankyou so much works perfectly!